# How to instantiate the same struct with different implementations of a trait?

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I have a trait that is implemented by the same struct in different ways. In order to accomplish this I have different structs that have different implementations. For abstraction I'm going to call these structs A-Z:

```
trait Trait {
    fn bar<T: Trait> (&self, z: &Struct3<T>) -> Struct3<T>;
}
```

```
struct StructA {
    name: String,
    color: String,
}
impl Trait for StructA {
    fn bar<T: Trait> (&self, z: &Struct3<T>) -> Struct3<T>{

        let mut list = Vec::new();
        list.push(self.clone());

        let y = Struct2::<T> {
            name: z.y.name,
            list: list,
        };

        Struct3::<T> {
            point: 1,
            y: y,
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct StructZ {
    name: String,
    color: String,
}
impl Trait for StructZ {
    fn bar<T: Trait> (&self, z: &Struct3<T>) -> Struct3<T>{

        let mut list = Vec::new();
        list.push(self.clone());

        let y = Struct2::<T> {
            name: z.y.name,
            list: list,
        };

        Struct3::<T> {
            point: 26,
            y: y,
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to approach this so that each instance of the struct has a different implementation of the trait, or is making a new struct the best way to go?

I am new to compiled languages. Most of the work I have done has been using Python and TypeScript.

Comment: Is the only difference the `point` value? or is it more complicated than that? how would you do this in Python or Typescript?

Comment: It is more complicated than this example. I simplified to make it easier to ask.  In python, or an OO language for that matter, I would make the trait an interface and implement it with a base class. Then, I would extend that base class with classes A...Z

Comment: @WhyNot I think you're trying to stick a bit too hard on a object-oriented pattern x) Rust does not have a concept of inheritance so problems are often fixed quite differently. I suggest you to precise your intent.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to figure a better way of refactoring it then. I was pressed so hard on OO principles in university, but I've been trying to break that habit. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do that is to make your trait generic over some type (even if this type is actually not used inside of the trait).

```rust
trait Trait<T> { /* ... */ }
```

That enables you to implement it multiple times for the same struct.

```rust
impl Trait<bool> for Struct { /* ... */ }
impl Trait<u32> for Struct { /* ... */ }
```

Here, `bool` and `u32` just become compile time flags to chose the implementation of `Trait` that you want to use.

```rust
let struct_3a = Trait::<bool>::bar(&my_object, /* ... */);
let struct_3b = Trait::<u32>::bar(&my_object, /* ... */);
```

I used `bool` and  `u32` here, but you can use your own types here to make everything clearer.

Comment: This is a really good idea I will probably use this at some point! Unfortunately the actual number of structs A...Z will be in the thousands, so I don't think this will work for this implementation. This is a really interesting hack though.

Comment: You can use empty structs like `struct VariantA;` instead of primitive types like `bool` for the generic trait; this might make it clearer and eliminate concerns with scalability.

Comment: Agree with @DanR . You can also make things easier by hooking the impl with an enum that contains the different types.